# recharts piechart animation flickers rather than loading smoothly

Tags: javascript, reactjs, css-animations, rendering, recharts

I have a file, Table.js, that is making a call to the database and mapping the data to my global store. I am then doing some quick math with that data in the Piecharts.js file and using it for the values in my recharts donut chart. The problem is, when it loads, it cuts right to the end of the animation. However, when I delete LRTable.js and just manually plug in a random number to the piechart, it loads nicely with a smooth animation. The same thing is happening with the other types of charts from recharts.

I have tried hiding the piecharts until the data loads and then showing them, but it still jumps right to the end of the animation. Nothing else that I found online seems applicable. I suspect there is something going on with the rendering with React that I do not yet fully comprehend.

**Table.js**

```
function Table() {

    const location = useLocation();
    const [state, dispatch] = useContext(LessonDataContext);
    const user = window.localStorage.getItem('user')

    const getNum = (val) => {
        if (isNaN(val)) {
          return 0;
        }
        return val;
     }

     const percent = (val) => {
        const strng = 'state.' + val + '[0]/state.' + val + '[1]';
        return String(getNum(eval(strng)).toFixed(1) * 100) + '%';
     }

     const correct = (val) => {
        const numerator = eval('state.' + val + '[0]')
        const denominator = eval('state.' + val + '[1]')
        return numerator + '/' + denominator
     }

//...

useEffect(() => {
        axios.get(`http://localhost:8000/api/submittedanswer/?user=${user}`, {
                headers: {
                    "Content-Type": "application/json",
                    Authorization: `Token ${window.localStorage.getItem('auth_token')}`,
                },
                })
                .then((resp) => {
                    resp.data.map((answer) => {

                        switch (answer.question.question_type){
                
                            case 'Flaw': {
                                const result = (answer.answer_choice == answer.question.correct_answer);
                                dispatch({type: 'flaw', correct: result});
                                break;
                            }
                            case 'Necessary Assumption': {
                                const result = (answer.answer_choice == answer.question.correct_answer);
                                dispatch({type: 'necessary_assumption', correct: result})
                                break;
                            }
                            case 'Sufficient Assumption': {
                                const result = (answer.answer_choice == answer.question.correct_answer);
                                dispatch({type: 'sufficient_assumption', correct: result})
                                break;
                            }
                            default: { break;}
                        }
                    })
                })
                .catch((err) => {})
    },[])

//...
```

**Piecharts.js**

```
function Piecharts() {

    const [state, dispatch] = useContext(LessonDataContext);
    const lr_value = String(Math.round((state.lr_total[0] / state.lr_total[1]) * 1000)/10) + '%';
    const lrProportionCorrect = state.lr_total[0] / state.lr_total[1];
    const lrProportionIncorrect = 1 - state.lr_total[0] / state.lr_total[1];
    const lrCorrectOverTotal = String(state.lr_total[0]) + '/' +  String(state.lr_total[1]) 


    const data = [
        { name: 'Group A', value: lrProportionCorrect },
        { name: 'Group B', value: lrProportionIncorrect },
      ];

      const COLORS = ["#C1E1C1", '#FF6961'];

    return (
        <S.PieChartContainer>
             <S.LabeledPieChart>
                    LR
                    <PieChart width={200} height={190} >
                        <Pie
                            data={data}
                            innerRadius={70}
                            outerRadius={80}
                            fill="#8884d8"
                            paddingAngle={0}
                            dataKey="value"
                            >
                            <Label value={lr_value} offset={0} position="center" />
                            {data.map((entry, index) => (
                                <Cell key={`cell-${index}`} fill={COLORS[index % COLORS.length]} />
                            ))}
                        </Pie>
                    </PieChart>
                    {lrCorrectOverTotal}
                </S.LabeledPieChart>
        </S.PieChartContainer>
    )
}
```